# Gammu Sql Customization on smsdrc to Limit SMS send per-hour and per-day

Tags: mysql, sql, gammu

It would be nice if you have solution for my problem :
I have to limit the sms sent by gammu for maksimum 150 sms per-hour.
This means if the gammu starts send sms at 08:00 PM and finish sent 150 sms at 08:20 PM. the next period will be 09:00 PM to sent another 150 sms

And the daily quota will be 1000 sms

I have tried this one :
[sql]
find_outbox_sms_id=SELECT ID, InsertIntoDB, SendingDateTime, SenderID FROM outbox WHERE SendingDateTime < NOW() AND SendingTimeOut <  NOW() AND SendBefore >= CURTIME() AND SendAfter <= CURTIME() AND (isnull(SenderID)  OR SenderID = '') and (select count(1) FROM sentitems WHERE SenderID = '' and TIMESTAMPDIFF(hour,SendingDateTime,now()) < 1) < 150 ORDER BY SendingDateTime ASC LIMIT 1

But it doesnt work.
Any help would be great for me.

Answer (score 0):

There is no rate limiting in Gammu. You can use [monitor](https://wammu.eu/docs/manual/smsd/monitor.html) tool to check how many messages have been sent and stop daemon after limit has been reached.

Comment: Yes, there is no rate limiting in Gammu SMSD right now. But patches implementing it are welcome :-)

Comment: hmm, im still thinking that [sql] section in smsdrc could do something about it.

Comment: Maybe, though I'm not sure how to construct SQL like "select one record from outbox if sentitems has less then 150 records in last hour". Anyway you could rephrase the question like this and add SQL tag to get help for this audience as well.